# Eclipse Subversive plugin: Why can't I create this branch?

Tags: eclipse, svn, branch, subversive

I recently switched from Subclipse to Subversive for SVN integration in Eclipse, and I'm having trouble creating a branch of my source code.

I've tried a few different variations of my method, but they all led me to the same roadblock. Basically, here's what I'm trying to do.

- Navigator pane
- Right-click on project folder (want to branch the whole thing)
- Team > Branch
- In the **Location** field, browse to select the /branches folder in my repository
- Add the branch name to the path field, i.e. "/testbranch" (not pictured)

The dialog then looks like this, and I can't continue.

http://img820.imageshack.us/img820/1011/branchingfail.png

What am I doing wrong here? Why can't I create this branch? If nothing else, can it at least be confirmed that I'm following the right process, and it's something about my environment or configuration that's stopping the branch from being created?

Answer (score 0):

I found that SVN is very particular with the SVN connectors. If you connected and downloaded SVN code with one connector and then switched to a different connector when you started using Subversive, you'll definitely have problems.

I've had unexplained Subversive problems in the past and they've almost always tracked back to different connector usage. The solution for me was to reset all of my local SVN code. I deleted everything local and rechecked out all of my code. Everything appeared to be fine after that.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Well, that definitely applies here. Worth a shot!

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't fix my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I don't consider this a proper solution, but it's at least got me working again. Instead of running a branch operation, I created a new folder inside my branches folder, and then copied the contents of the trunk folder into it. I was then able to switch to my new "branch".

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you do not have any uncommited changes, and then do a Team>cleanup.  Also make sure you are branching from the trunk and that you do not have any mixed version.  For example you can have a folder below the root be from another branch while the rest of the project is from trunk.  This will cause the branch creation to fail.  When having issues with branches from the navigator, try reverting the project (right click choose team>revert) several times.  Then execute the cleanup several times.

Also you may consider creating the branch from the SVN Repositories view.  From this view right click on the location you want to branch from (ie truck) and select New>branch from the context menu.  One last step is from the navigator view you will need to swtich your project to the newly created brancn: right click on the project root and select Team>switch from the context menu